# How to increase the speed of adjacency list allocation?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

After deciding that **adjacency matrix** won't work out for **80513** nodes and **5899882** edges I've decided to apply **adjacency list**. It's my first implementation of adjacency list and basically I've decided to apply vector of vectors method.

Thus, for example, the **vectorOfVectors[5]** will be contain the neighbours of include the neighbours node **5**. The dataset I'm using can be found [here](http://socialcomputing.asu.edu/datasets/Flickr)

Currently I've written this code and it works without any error, however on my computer it takes 26 secs (i5 2.4 with 6 gb ram, running Win7). I was wondering if my code could be improved in order to reduce the allocation speed.

**PS:**  I'm using **fstream** library and reading from a **.csv** file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("edges.csv");
    string word="",data="";
    getline(file,word);
    int arrTemp[3];
    int numberOfNodes=atoi(word.c_str());
    vector<int>temp;
    vector< vector<int> >adjacencyList;

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfNodes;i++)
    {
        adjacencyList.push_back(temp);
    }
    while(file.good() && getline(file,word))
    {
        //cout<<word<<endl;
        if(word.size()>0)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                int cutFrom=word.find_first_of(',');
                arrTemp[i]=atoi(word.substr(0,cutFrom).c_str());
                word=word.substr(cutFrom+1,word.length());
            }
            //cout<<arrTemp[0]<<" "<<arrTemp[1]<<endl;
            adjacencyList[arrTemp[0]-1].push_back(arrTemp[1]-1);

        }
        else
            break;
    }

    cout<<"Vector size:"<<adjacencyList[1].size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should go on Codereview.

Comment: If you'd like help choosing a data representation that suits your problem, you can ask on [cs.se]. On CS, you'd need to explain your problem in English or math, you can't expect people to know C++. If you want to stick with this data representation and are looking for ways to make the C++ implementation more efficient, this is the right place.

Comment: @Gilles First of all, thanks for the detailed description. However what I'm really looking for is the last one you said above. I'd like to improve the code above, increase my C++ implementation more efficient. A whole different data structure wouldn't be helpful for me at this time, anyway.

Comment: Just a thought: code for parsing the CSV should be separate from code that actually populates the `adjacency list`. And please please use more spaces in your code.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be an `unordered_set` of node index pairs (where pairs always list the smaller node first).

Answer (score 0):

You can preallocate memory for adjacencyList with adjacencyList.reserve(numberOfNodes). That will reduce unnecessary memory allocations and copying of data around.

Also with Visual Studio in Debug mode, STL runtime keeps track of all iterators and this makes work with huge containers slow sometimes. Orders of magnitude between Debug/Release are not uncommon. Research "debug iterator support" for more info.